# ccmake using cmake version 3.10

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install the new ITK version which needs a cmake version higher than 3.9

I have just download the cmake 3.10 version.
and when I install it there is no ccmake in the bin folder. usually the new ccmake version is here.

when I want to install ccmake using apt it links it to the 3.5 cmake version.

How can I do to have a ccmake version linked to the 3.10 version of cmake ?

Comment: The question is if you really need `ccmake`. Isn't `cmake` enought?

Comment: I find that ccmake simplify a lot to chose which module I want to install, to set so variable etc .... it makes cmake really easier to use in my opinion

Comment: See [How do I install the latest version of cmake from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/865294/547800)

Comment: I did that already as said. but even if cmake works, I don't have ccmake

Comment: I've given it a try and yes you also need `curses` library to build `ccmake`. I've summarized the necessary steps in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

You can use the following tutorial to build and install the latest CMake version: [How do I install the latest version of cmake from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line/865294#865294)

**But** - as for the time of your question - it was lacking the hint to install the `curses` library/headers first (see [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-January/053358.html),
 you don't get `ccmake` built and installed without it ). So I had the same problem on my Ubuntu and was able to [install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270381/how-do-i-install-ncurses-header-files) and rebuild it with the following steps:

```
# sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
# cd ~/temp/cmake-3.10.2
# cmake .
...
# make -j8
...
# sudo make install
... 
# ccmake
Usage

  ccmake <path-to-source>
  ccmake <path-to-existing-build>

Specify a source directory to (re-)generate a build system for it in the
current working directory.  Specify an existing build directory to
re-generate its build system.

Run 'ccmake --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

The binary `ccmake` is a target of the make file.

To get all, perform:

```
./configure
make all
sudo make install
```

To just get `ccmake`, perform:

```
make ccmake
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I still have only cmake version 3.10 and cpack

Comment: Are you in a fresh folder just created? Are there any build errors? Does `echo $?` just performed after every step print `0` always?

Comment: you mean once I have type ./configure. it tells me cmake has bootstrapped. now run make. and now in the terminal I type echo $? if I do that it print 0 yes. then I perform make all -j 8, everything seems ok and then echo $? print 0. and then the make install. again everything seems ok. and echo $? print 0. and I still have in the /bin cmake, cpack but not ccmake.