# cmake target_compile_features C++17

Tags: cmake, c++17

Adhering to the best practice for modern CMake I want to use this command instead of flags or set-based commands. However, I cant seem to make it work, since I cannot find associated commands for the newly introduced C++17 features. For C++14 I can do something along the following lines

```
target_compile_features(Foo
  PUBLIC
    cxx_strong_enums
  PRIVATE
    cxx_lambdas
)
```

I guess what I am asking is, what is the proper way to enable the latest standard of C++ in cmake without resorting back to legacy cmake

Answer (score 2):

You're going in the right direction, you may just need to update your CMake version.

It started with [CMake Version 3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.8.html#id6):

> The Compile Features functionality is now aware of C++ 17. No specific features are yet enumerated besides the `cxx_std_17` meta-feature.

For VS you need e.g. at least CMake Version 3.10.

**References**

- [How to enable /std:c++17 in VS2017 with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960715/how-to-enable-stdc17-in-vs2017-with-cmake)
- [ccmake using cmake version 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682956/ccmake-using-cmake-version-3-10)