# cmake/cpack component debuginfo rpm package doesn't appear

Tags: c++, cmake, rpm, cpack

CentOS6.9 / cmake 3.6.1

On my project I'm trying to create several components, than build runtime, devel and debuginfo packages for them, but I was unable to produce more than one rpm for each component. I created small project to show the problem:

./include/Box.hpp

```
namespace room {

class Box {
public:
    Box(int volume);
    int get_volume() const;
private:
    int m_volume;
};

}
```

./source/Box.cpp

```
#include "Box.hpp"

namespace room {

Box::Box(int volume)
    : m_volume(volume)
{
}

int Box::get_volume() const
{
    return this->m_volume;
}

}
```

./source/app.cpp

```
#include "Box.hpp"

int main() {
    room::Box box(5);
    return box.get_volume();
}
```

./CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project (home)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RelWithDebInfo")

include_directories("include")
file(GLOB SRC_FILES "source/*.cpp")
file(GLOB HDR_FILES "include/*.hpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})
install(FILES ${HDR_FILES} DESTINATION "include" COMPONENT devel)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin" COMPONENT devel)

set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL devel)

set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_DEBUG 1)
set(CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
set(CPACK_RPM_DEVEL_FILE_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}-devel.rpm")

set(CPACK_RPM_DEVEL_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE ON)
set(CPACK_RPM_DEVEL_DEBUGINFO_FILE_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}-devel-debuginfo.rpm")
include(CPack)
```

console:

```
$ mkdir BUILD && cd BUILD && cmake3 .. && make -j5 && make package
```

But after this actions I see only one 'devel' rpm and no rpm with debuginfo. I looked at documentation and couldn't find any idea where I am wrong. Could someone clarify it to me? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you read [MCVE] before doing this or are you just a logical question asker? Take 5 rep!

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**

Your example is generally working, you probably just need to update your CMake version.

**The Details**

I couldn't reproduce your problem with my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and CMake 3.10.2. There is a `./BUILD/home-devel-debuginfo.rpm` generated.

So three things I've noticed with your given example:

1. The [`CPACK_RPM_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPackRPM.html#packaging-of-debug-information) was introduced in [CMake Version 3.7](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.7.html#cpack). So the first line of your `CMakeLists.txt` should be:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
   ```

   For some more details on updating your CMake to the latest version on Linux see ["ccmake using cmake version 3.10"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682956/ccmake-using-cmake-version-3-10).

   If you want to find which CMake version is the minimum to support a certain feature - since this is not part of CMake's official documentation - please see ["Finding which CMake version a feature was introduced in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844358/finding-which-cmake-version-a-feature-was-introduced-in).
2. The documentation says the variable `CPACK_BUILD_SOURCE_DIRS` is mandatory. And if I add the following line, I get rid of a lot of `rpm` generation warnings:

   ```
   set(CPACK_BUILD_SOURCE_DIRS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
   ```
3. There was a dependency of packaging `debuginfo` to the `elfutils` package. So I had to do:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install elfutils
   ```

Comment: @hvd Yes, I just hadn't a CMake version 3.6.1 available to really test it. I'll should rephrase to "Your example is generally working, you probably just need to update your CMake version".