# CMake Version Problem during Configuration of CCMake

Tags: cmake, vtk

I have installed **CMake** **3.15.2** for my project.Then I configure and build **VTK**.Finally I install **CCMake** with following command.

`sudo apt  install cmake-curses-gui`

The version of **CCMake** which has been installed is **3.10.2**.After opening CCMake window,for setting up the paths and others, I get following image.

[image: CCMake Window]

Then when I press **[c]** for configuration, I get following error message.

[image: CCMake Configuration Error]

From the error , it seems to me that the version of **CMake** used by **CCMake**  is lower than the version **VTK** requires.Though installed **CMake** version is **3.15.2**.But **CMake** version in **CCMake is 3.10.2**.During **configuration** ,**VTK** checks this version which is creating problem.I have tried to upgrade the version of **CCMake** , but don't get anything above **3.10.2**.I have also followed solutions of following question which is same as mine.

[ccmake using cmake version 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682956/ccmake-using-cmake-version-3-10)

But can't solve.
Dear altruists , how can I solve it? Any suggestion will be appreciated.And thanks in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu? If so, https://apt.kitware.com/ lets you install the latest CMake. I have an answer on askubuntu mentioning this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1138455/762119

Comment: How did you install CMake 3.15.2?  I would remove the CCMake installed via apt-get.  IMHO the best bet is to compile and install your own CMake from the source code.

Comment: I don't have problem using **CMake**. I have installed 3.15.2 from source code.But problem arises , when I go to use **CCMake**.What can I do to suggest CCMake to use **CMake** 3.15.2 instead of **3.10.2**

Comment: "I have also followed solutions of following question which is same as mine...But can't solve." - This is a problem statement, with which we simply cannot help you. What **exactly** is going wrong when you followed that approach about installing `cmake` with ncurses available?

Comment: If you have built and installed CMake from source, then CCMake should also have been built and installed at the same time.  It should be in the same location (/usr/local/bin by default).

Comment: @Tsyvarev problem is I am not able to configure CMake curses gui (CCMake). As a result I can't use the command line. Whenever I press **[c]** for configuration , It displays an error message (Kindly take a look at second image in my question). Actually, I need to configure CCMake successfully.

Comment: The screenshots in your question are (as far as I understand) about **building your project**, which uses VTK. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48694539/3440745) you refers to is about **building CMake** itself. So, have you tried to: 1.Install development package of `ncurses`. 2. Build (or rebuild) CMake 3.15.2 from sources and install it. 3. Use `ccmake` provided by this installation?

Comment: Yes. I have tried all 3 things. They have been executed successfully.But this solution is not solving my issue.Due to similarity of question, I have referred to it.My ultimate problem is not **cmake building** .It is **version problem of cmake**.Now please focus on my last screenshot where it says **vtk found false**.Then **VTK requires cmake 3.12 in order to reliably be used**. At the bottom part u will see **cmake version 3.10.2** .This conflict needs to be resolved.Please consider it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,the problem was created due to a condition in vtk-config.cmake file. The condition was

[image]

That's why

- VTK_FOUND Set to False
- Show the message **VTK requires cmake 3.12 in order to reliably be used**

I have changed the version of CMake in the condition like following image.

[image]

Now it works fine.Reason of giving **3.10** is my CMake version is 3.10.2 which you will find in the second screenshot of my question.You will update it according to your installed version. Finally I needed one more change.In the vtk-config.cmake file, you will see **cmake_policy()**.With it the version of CMake can be set. Initially it was
`cmake_policy(VERSION 3.12)`. After my edition it is `cmake_policy(VERSION 3.10)`.
Without edition I have faced following error

- `An attempt was made to set the policy version of CMake to "3.12" which is greater than this version of CMake.  This is not allowed because the greater version may have new policies not known to this CMake.  You may need a newer CMake version to build this project.`

That's all.